# Apache OAK Direct Binary Access with S3DataStore

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I'm trying to figure out how the direct binary access feature works with Apache Oak.

My understanding so far is, I can set binary properties to nodes, and later, I should be able to get a direct download link (from S3).

First, I created a node and added a binary property with the contents of some file.

```
val ntFile = session.getRootNode.addNode(path, "nt:file")
val ntResource = ntFile.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource")

ntResource.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", "application/octet-stream")
ntResource.setProperty("jcr:lastModified", Calendar.getInstance())

val fStream = new FileInputStream("/home/evren/cast.webm")
val bin = session.getValueFactory.asInstanceOf[JackrabbitValueFactory].createBinary(fStream)
ntResource.setProperty("jcr:data", bin)
```

And I can see on the AWS Console, my binary is uploaded.

But, still, I cannot generate direct download URI, even following the documentation on the OAK website. (So the code continues)

```
session.save()
session.refresh(false)

val binary = session.getRootNode.getNode(path)
  .getNode("jcr:content").getProperty("jcr:data").getValue.getBinary

val uri = binary.asInstanceOf[BinaryDownload].getURI(BinaryDownloadOptions.DEFAULT)
```

It's always returning null.

Someone please could point me to what I am doing wrong or is my understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One interesting finding is, I can get a direct download Url for a binary property using `getContentIdentity` method of `JackRabbitValue` . This retuns an identifier in <identifier>#<some_number>. And If I parse the identifier, then I can get the download url using S3DataStore's `getDownloadURI` method. 

Does anybody know what is this number here and why do we need to parse the identifier? This looks like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In case, anyone else is facing the same issue, the trick is to register your BlobStore using a `WhiteBoard`.

This explains a lot about the issue that, I could upload files directly using BlobStorage but OAK itself could not use the BlobStore functionality to get a direct download link.

```scala
val wb = new DefaultWhiteboard()

// register s3/azure as BlobAccessProvider
wb.register(
   classOf[BlobAccessProvider],
   blobStore.asInstanceOf[BlobAccessProvider],
   Collections.emptyMap()
)

val jcrRepo = new Jcr(nodeStore).`with`(wb).createRepository()
```

And once you create your JCR Repo like this, direct binary download/upload works as expected.